# Popover menu and Bootstrap (it doesn't appear with the right width)

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, css

I'm trying to develop a panel for a popup menu when you are over a link in the bootstrap navbar. I have several problems to achieve the right width.

HTML

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-lower">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-2" aria-expanded="false">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>

                </button>


            </div><!-- navbar-header -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-2">

                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <a href="#" class="pull-left" style="margin-right: 10px;">
                    <img id="logo" src="assets/img/sendingparcel/logo.png" ></img>
                    </a>
                                        <li class="active">
                        <a href="#">
                            Home
                            <span class="sr-only">
                                (current)
                            </span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="menu">
                        <a href="#">
                            Sturen
                        </a>


                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">
                            Ontvangen
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">
                            Zakelijke oplossingen
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">
                            Klandentiest
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">
                            E-Shop
                        </a>
                    </li>

                </ul>
                {% include popmenu.html %}



            </div> <!-- collapse navbar-collapse -->


        </div>
    </nav><!-- end navbar navbar-default -->
```

The popmenu code is the following:

```
   <div class="popover">
    <div class="row"  style="display: none;">
        <div class="col-md-12 ">

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <span class="titlel3">Zakelijk pakjes sturen</span>
                        <hr>
                        <em>Wat kan ik versturen?<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-right" style="font-size:11px;"></span></em><br>
                        <em>Onze oplossingen<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-right" style="font-size:11px;"></span></em><br><br>
                        <ul>
                            <li>
                                Nationaal
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                Internationaal
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                Sprintlevering
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                Retour
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                Fullfillment
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <span class="titlel3">Retouroplossingen</span>
                        <hr>
                        <em>Lorem<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-right" style="font-size:11px;"></span></em><br>
                        <em>Ipsum<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-right" style="font-size:11px;"></span></em><br>
                        <em>Dolor<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-right" style="font-size:11px;"></span></em><br>
                        <br><br>
                        <span class="titlel3">Voor webshops</span>
                        <hr>
                        <em>Lorem<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-right" style="font-size:11px;"></span></em><br>
                        <em>Ipsum<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-right" style="font-size:11px;"></span></em><br>
                        <em>Dolor<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-right" style="font-size:11px;"></span></em><br>


                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <span class="titlel3">Mail sturen</span>
                        <hr>
                        <em>Lorem<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-right" style="font-size:11px;"></span></em><br>
                        <em>Ipsum<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-right" style="font-size:11px;"></span></em><br>
                        <em>Dolor<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-right" style="font-size:11px;"></span></em><br>
                        <br><br>
                        <span class="titlel3">Ontvangen</span>
                        <hr>
                        <em>Lorem<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-right" style="font-size:11px;"></span></em><br>
                        <em>Ipsum<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-right" style="font-size:11px;"></span></em><br>
                        <em>Dolor<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-right" style="font-size:11px;"></span></em><br>

                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <span class="titlel3">Mail sturen</span>
                        <hr>
                        <em>Lorem<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-right" style="font-size:11px;"></span></em><br>
                        <em>Ipsum<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-right" style="font-size:11px;"></span></em><br>
                        <em>Dolor<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-right" style="font-size:11px;"></span></em><br>
                        <br><br>
                        <span class="titlel3">Ontvangen</span>
                        <hr>
                        <em>Lorem<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-right" style="font-size:11px;"></span></em><br>
                        <em>Ipsum<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-right" style="font-size:11px;"></span></em><br>
                        <em>Dolor<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-right" style="font-size:11px;"></span></em><br>

                    </div>

                </div><!-- row -->

            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

And this is the style:

```
 .popover{
    max-width: 100%;
    top: 40px;
    left: 0px;
    position:absolute;
    display:none;
    border: 2px solid red;
    padding-bottom: 2%;
}
```

This is my last attempt but in any case I can't understand why the width is limited.

[image]

Comment: It would be helpful to see a fiddle or example that people can look at

Comment: It is impossible to reproduce it stand-alone... have a look at the picture

Answer (score 0):

`.col-md-3` in bootstrap has a defined width, you are only overiding the `max-width`

Try adding `width: auto;` to your css:

```
.col-md-3.popover {
   width: auto;
   max-width: 100%;
   top: 40px;
   left: -28px;
   position:absolute;
   display:none;
   border: 2px solid red;
}
```

Comment: Have a look at my new code... the second attempt pls

Comment: If you set the .popover to have a `min-width: 525px` does it work? @SilvioS.